# Use an image from a private docker repository as GitLab CI/CD service

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

We want to run our E2E tests in a GitLab CI pipeline. For this purpose we also want to launch our backend(s) as service(s). The problem is that these images are stored on a private docker repository and GitLab cannot pull them because of this error:

```
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: unauthorized to access repository: PRIVATE, action: pull: unauthorized to access repository: PRIVATE, action: pull (docker.go:131:0s)
```

The gitlab CI/CD config looks as follows:

```
test:
  services:
    - mongo:4.4.19
    - mariadb:10.7.8
    - name: PRIVATE
      alias: private-container
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" PRIVATE
```

I tried using the `before_script` keyword to login to the repository:

```
before_script:
    - docker login -u "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" PRIVATE
```

But it seems that the services are getting launched before the `before_script` gets executed. Did anyone try something similar? Is this the right approach?

Comment: i think you should use other ways to login your private repository, instead of using **before_script**. **1.** [how to login docker acccount in gitlab-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406689/how-to-login-docker-account-in-gitlab-ci),**2.** If your version is newer  than 13.9, refer this: [Use the Dependency Proxy for Docker images](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/dependency_proxy/#use-the-dependency-proxy-for-docker-images)