# GitLab CI/CD pipeline issue docker login failed

Tags: gitlab-ci, devops, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

How can fix this issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18N3v.png)

I tried enter to registry from VPS it is login success. But when running this pipeline it is failed with registry login error. How can solve this Issue?

I need perfect answer for solving this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation for auth in docker using the CI/CD way.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/authenticate_registry.html

[How to login docker account in Gitlab-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406689/how-to-login-docker-account-in-gitlab-ci)